# Is $C^1[a,b]$ separable space?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Is $C^1[a,b]$ separable space with norm $||f||=\int_{a}^{b}\left | f(x) \right |dx$? with norm $||f||=(\int_{a}^{b} f(x)^{2}dx)^{1/2}$?

I have read with theorems about base but I am confused. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

The polynomials with real coefficients constitute a dense (albeit uncountable, but bear with me) subspace ${\cal P}$.  (To see why it is dense in the $L^2$-norm, recall that the polynomials are dense in the $\sup$-norm by the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem, and that convergence in the $\sup$ norm implies convergence in the $L^2$-norm.)

In turn, the polynomials with rational coefficients constitute a countable subspace dense in ${\cal P}$, hence also in your space.

Comment: The polynomials are uncountable unless you take their coefficients from a countable set.

Comment: @carmichael561 Good point, thanks.  Are the polynomials with rational coefficients dense in those with real ones?  If so, I can patch things up.  Seems like they should be.

Comment: Yes, that should be fine.

Comment: Corrected.  Thanks again.

Comment: @user8960 on $[-1,1]$. as $ n \to \infty$ : $(1-x^2)^n$ is clearly a polynomial approximation of $1_{|x | < \epsilon}$, so its shifts are dense in all the common function spaces

Comment: @user1952009, good construct, but don't we still need to worry about the countability of the space generated by the shifts?  So, shifts by a rational number?

Comment: @user8960 yes of course, for example shifts by $a /2^b$. And $(1- x^2/4)^n$ is easier to manage (since it is stricly decreasing on $[0,2]$)